# Appending To a New List In Python If Value Is True

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function which returns a copy of a list with the non true elements removed. I tried to go at it like this:

```
def compact(lst):
"""Return a copy of lst with non-true elements removed.

    >>> compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])
    [1, 2, 'All done']
"""
new_list = []
for element in lst:
    if element == True:
        new_list.append(element)

return new_list
```

However when using the provided test:

```
compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])
```

It only returns [1] rather than the expected [1,2,'All Done']. If I simply remove the conditional the function will print every value, so seemingly something is off with the logic checking if something is a True value.

Comment: You're confusing true and `True`.

Comment: `return [x for x in lst if x]`

Comment: You could just use `if element:` rather than `if element == True:`. The problem is that the Boolean value `True` is only one type of "truthy" value. If you find it confusing, you are not alone. Python has a Boolean type, but also a semantics which allows for arbitrary values to sometimes function as Boolean values. There is a reason for this, but it is hard to get a good mental model for it when you are first learning the language.

Comment: Thanks guys! Seems super obvious now but was frustrating me for a little while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `== True` from your code:

```
def compact(lst):
    """Return a copy of lst with non-true elements removed.
    
    >>> compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])
    [1, 2, 'All done']
    """
    new_list = []
    for element in lst:
        if element:
            new_list.append(element)

    return new_list 
    
compact([0, 1, 2, '', [], False, (), None, 'All done'])
```

To see why, try running code like `1 == True` and `2 == True`.